# Menu Contols like the Office 2007 Ribbon

Tags: c#, winforms, office-2007, ribbon-control

Is there a way to my WinApp written in C# using Visual Studio 2008 have menu controls which look like on these We can fund in Office 2007.
[Menu http://lh6.ggpht.com/_l7ldTfcnI34/S0wk1-eGSYI/AAAAAAAAEYU/IrTyYDV2Muo/s800/menus.jpg](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_l7ldTfcnI34/S0wk1-eGSYI/AAAAAAAAEYU/IrTyYDV2Muo/s800/menus.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get a free license to incorporate the Office 2007 user interface into your program.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx

Comment: Microsoft has set some guidelines with Office 2007 interface. Microsoft doesnt offer controls in C#.NET or VB.NET to implement Office 2007 look and feel. If you have visual studio 2008 SP1 you can use MFC which has Office2007/Docking support. However, i suggest go for free solution mentioned in my answer. If you find that doesnt solve your project needs then you may invest in some commercial toolkit.

Comment: Oh i forgot microsoft forbids you to use the office 2007 in a software which may be a rival to MS-Office products. From the link http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E2DDD3FB-8635-4D54-8730-102B75C31DB6&displaylang=en it states "The license is available for applications on any platform, except for applications that compete directly with the five Office applications that currently have the new UI (Microsoft Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Outlook and Access)."

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a free control from microsoft, but there are a bunch of people who will sell you a version. DivElements.co.uk are one example (no affiliation).

Microsoft only have a version for C++ and for WPF, not for winforms.

Answer (score 1):

Well, out of the box from VS.NET, the toolbar controls aren't anywhere near what you want in Office apps.

You can write your own custom ones or simply get 3rd party components.

E.g.:
http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/MenusandToolbarsWinForms/
etc etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Telerik RadRibbonBar For WinForms by registering at this link below
http://www.microsoft.com/express/registration/

this provides you with a free ribbon bar control which you can use with C# in your application and can even distribute the applications without any royalities to Telerik.

Otherwise like stated in other answers you would need to buy some commericial toolkit like DevExpress etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here it comes to WPF http://fluent.codeplex.com/